# rails generate - creates migration with an old table name and rails keeps looking for non existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I used to refer to a table named "people" but decided to change that to "person"
I completely removed all references to table "people"
But rails keeps referring to this old "people" table and I am not sure where there could still be a reference to this table.

I removed the fixtures and all the migration scripts and also did the following
rails destroy model Person
rails destroy model People

- hoping that will clear any other references etc..
  recreated persons controller and when i tried to generate model Person (corresponding to persons table ), it creates a "create table" migration script.

I am using MYSQL

```
C:\RubyApps\RRApp>rails generate model Person
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20151025203042_create_people.rb
      create    app/models/person.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/person_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/people.yml

-----------

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PersonsController#show
Mysql2::Error: Table 'rr.people' doesn't exist: SELECT `people`.* FROM `people` WHERE `people`.`personid` IS NULL LIMIT 1

Rails.root: C:/RubyApps/RRApp

----------------
```

Appreciate any inputs on this. thank you!

Comment: please paste db/migrate/20151025203042_create_people.rb and your schema.rb please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Rails expect your table name to be a pluralized form of your model and it is [smart enough](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions) to understand that pluralized `Person` becomes `people`.

If you insist on your custom table name (I'd not advise that), you can override it via the following code:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "person"
end
```

Don't forget to change table name to `person` in your migration too.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey.. That makes total sense!. I was puzzled. I agree with you on following the rails methodology. In this case, I will not name these table names person or people , but something else which will avoid these situations.. BTW, your suggestion worked!! thanks again.